# opencv 画像の表示ができない

Tags: python

プログラミング初心者です。

Jupiter notebook 上でpython3を起動しています。

デスクトップ上に保存したsample.jpgをjupyter notebookでインライン上に表示したいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

pathが問題だと思うのですが、pathの位置や通す方法がわからず、検索もしてみたのですが理解できません。アドバイスをお願い致します。

**プログラム**

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

**エラー**

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-98760eafe379> in <module>
      3 import cv2
      4 img = cv2.imread("prius.jpg")
----> 5 plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
      6 plt.show()

error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

Answer (score 1):

`sample.jpg` が今編集している Notebook と同じパスにあれば、このソースコードで表示できるはずです。

`%pwd` で現在のワーキングディレクトリが出力できるので、想定のものと一致しているかご確認ください。